# Docker compose start detached process in gitlab ci

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I have the .gitlab-ci.yml

```
docker-build:
  # Official docker image.
  image: docker/compose:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker-compose up --build
    - docker-compose up -d &
  script:
    - pytest tests
  except:
    - master
```

I try to run the stack I have in the gitlab repository in order to test it with pytest integation tests
but I have realised that I can not start the stack as a detached process so the flow can continue to the `script` step.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it's getting 'stuck' on the first docker-compose command, as it's starting the containers without being detached.

Try doing everything in one line:

```
before_script:
  - docker-compose up -d --build
```

Or do a `docker-compose build` first and then do a `docker-compose up -d`